# hotkeys in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, hotkeys, windows-terminal

Is it possible to create a hotkey or batch file script (Sorry unsure if I am using the correct language for what I want) where in Windows Terminal hit `F1`

to run this below in Windows Terminal:
`alias python=python3.9`

I am just tired of having to enter this over and over and curious some sort of hotkey can be pressed to enter in this with one button press like `F1` key something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>F12</kbd>
to
your string:

```
F12::SendInput, alias python=python3.9
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 0):

harrymc's answer of Autohotkey is a good general-use way of adding hotkeys to Windows.  But I think there are two better solutions for your particular need.  The "best" way, if it works for you, is at the bottom here.

For Windows Terminal, Autohotkey is not necessary, since WT provides this capability out-of-the-box with the `sendInput` action.  At the time of this answer, adding Windows Terminal actions still requires editing its `settings.json` (which can be done through the Settings dropdown).

Add the following to your `"actions"` section.  Hopefully, I'm leaving the indention at the correct level so that you can just copy/paste, but do correct the indentation if needed:

```
       {
            "command": 
            {
                "action": "sendInput",
                "input": "alias python=python39\n"
            },
            "keys": "f12"
        },
```

But I'd really propose that if this is something you need in most of your sessions, then you should just add it to your shell's startup config.  Given your `alias` command, it *looks* like you are probably using `bash` as your shell, in which you should edit `~/.bashrc` to have it run automatically in any interactive session.